# Why does the WSO2 IS 5.6.0 SCIM2 Group API throw error when trying to insert or update users?

Tags: wso2, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to use the WSO2 Identity Server SCIM2 APIs to create and update users and groups.
However I am facing problems with the Group Update API (PUT /scim2/Groups/{id}): If I try to insert some user into the body of the message, the API always returns HTTP Error 500 ("Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block ").

Here's how to reproduce the failure:

1) First we create a user:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://auth-server:9444/scim2/Users/ \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: a43e26c0-fb00-4fa0-9482-74f62078d6b1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "emails": [{
        "type": "home",
        "value": "test.user@test.com.br",
        "primary": true
    }],
    "password": "test.user",
    "name": {
        "familyName": "Test",
        "givenName": "User"
    },
    "userName": "test.user"
}'
```

We receive as response HTTP 200 with body:

```
{
    "emails": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "value": "test.user@test.com.br",
            "primary": true
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "created": "2019-01-09T20:41:27Z",
        "location": "https://localhost:9444/scim2/Users/14fc39fc-1b0c-4db2-9e3a-bd5c522770bb",
        "lastModified": "2019-01-09T20:41:27Z",
        "resourceType": "User"
    },
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
    ],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "Test",
        "givenName": "User"
    },
    "id": "14fc39fc-1b0c-4db2-9e3a-bd5c522770bb",
    "userName": "test.user"
}
```

2) Next we create a group:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://auth-server:9444/scim2/Groups/ \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 45d2220d-d33d-42ba-8ce5-205646aa2963' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "displayName": "Application/Test",
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group"
    ]
}'
```

We receive as response HTTP 200 with body:

```
{
    "displayName": "APPLICATION/Test",
    "meta": {
        "created": "2019-01-09T20:43:22Z",
        "location": "https://localhost:9444/scim2/Groups/7feb0a54-18c5-4265-bdd6-7ceecd96bf0d",
        "lastModified": "2019-01-09T20:43:22Z",
        "resourceType": "Group"
    },
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group"
    ],
    "id": "7feb0a54-18c5-4265-bdd6-7ceecd96bf0d"
}
```

3) When we try to associate the newly created user with the group, we receive an HTTP 500 error. See below:

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://auth-server:9444/scim2/Groups/7feb0a54-18c5-4265-bdd6-7ceecd96bf0d \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic c2NpbS5kY2xvZ2c6c2NpbS5kY2xvZ2c=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6db43a33-af40-452e-83eb-40f8d6e3c5e3' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "displayName": "APPLICATION/Test",
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group"
    ],
    "members": [
        {
            "value": "14fc39fc-1b0c-4db2-9e3a-bd5c522770bb",
            "display": "test"
        }
    ]
}'
```

HTTP 500 error:

```
{
    "schemas": "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error",
    "detail": "Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block",
    "status": "500"
}
```

For authentication, I am using basic authentication, with the user "admin" of Identity Server; but I also tried to create a user with all possible permissions, but the error is always the same.
In the execution console I have tried to refine the log, however only the message below is displayed:

```
[2019-01-09 20:47:00,656] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Domain: APPLICATION is passed with the claim and user store manager is loaded for the given domain name.
[2019-01-09 20:47:00,658] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block
```

Does this Group API really work for update requests?

If anyone can help, I appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your request of adding a user to a group as follows, this works fine for me.

curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X PUT -d '{"displayName":"PRIMARY/manager","members":[{"value":"416aaa06-d9ed-465b-8ac4-1a321624d158","display":"test.user"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9444/scim2/Groups/5d6ffce8-fab8-45ee-a407-b1cae0e4ecee

Comment: Thank you. Your request worked. What I noticed is that if I create a group with displayName attribute "Application/Test", I got the HTTP 500 error when trying to associate users. But if I create a group with "PRIMARY" prefix, the update works fine.

Comment: Application/* roles are hybrid roles in WSO2 Identity Server domain. It is created when an OAuth app is created. Hence you can not update it. That's why you experience that behavior. It is not an issue. It is our behavior.